# Echo -e on MacOS

Tags: macos, shell, echo, e

I have a problem with printing signs `\n`. My script is make for bash and is set to posix=yes. When I ran program on Mac the printing to bash is done only by `echo "text here"`. But when I ran it on Ubuntu VM, then there must be `echo -e "text here` because, if there's not, then the program does not work correctly.

**The problem is**, when I try to run script with `echo -e` in MacOS Bash (not zsh), it will print to terminal `-e` and call that the is not switcher -e for echo.

Why is it doing, please?

To enter bash in terminal on mac I used command "bash"

Comment: Behavior changed between `bash` 3.2 and some 4.x version. Basically, `-e` is used to enable the POSIX behavior `echo` is supposed to exhibit in the first place. I would recommend using `printf` instead of `echo` to ensure portability.

Comment: (I can confirm that in `bash` 3.2, which is what `/bin/bash` is in macOS, correctly outputs `-e` when `bash` is in POSIX mode. For whatever reasons, later versions of `bash` still seem use their non-POSI-compliant `echo` when in POSIX mode.)

Comment: Edit the question to show a [mre], including a script file that reproduces the problem, and show the command you use to execute the script file, including the shell you are in when you start it. You may be executing the script using some shell other than bash.

Comment: If you would share the script, others could check it for problems

Comment: Ah, right: even with `--posix`, the `echo` command in particular is sensitive to the setting of *another* option, `xpg_echo`. I've posted an answer discussing how `echo` works before recommending (again, and like several other answers) to use `printf` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `-e` option to `bash`'s built-in `echo` is a non-POSIX extension that enables processing of backslashed characters according to the XSI extension to the POSIX standard.

POSIX `echo` is supposed to treat `-e` as an ordinary argument, not an option. You can see this behavior using `/bin/echo`, which is POSIX compliant and does not implement the XSI extension.

```
$ /bin/echo -e foo\\nbar
-e foo\nbar
```

In `bash` 3.2, the nonstandard extension `-e` can be used to enable the XSI extension:

```
$ /bin/bash -c 'echo -e foo\\nbar'
foo
bar
```

This can also be enabled using the `xpg_echo` option:

```
% /bin/bash -O xpg_echo -c 'echo foo\\nbar'
foo
bar
```

Turning POSIX mode on make `echo` POSIX-compliant *and* enables the XSI extension.

```
$ /bin/bash --posix  -c 'echo foo\\nbar'
foo
bar
$ /bin/bash --posix  -c 'echo -e foo\\nbar'
-e foo
bar
```

Now let's jump to `bash` 5.2. (I'm assuming there are no significant differences between any of the 4.x versions and 5.2; corrections welcome.) Plain `echo` behaves as in 3.2: no XSI extension and non-compliant with POSIX. `xpg_echo` also works as before:

```
$ bash -c 'echo foo\\nbar'
foo\nbar
$ bash -c 'echo -e foo\\nbar'
foo
bar
$ bash -O xpg_echo -c 'echo foo\\nbar'
foo
bar
```

`--posix` behaves a little differently, and in my opinion is buggy.  In POSIX mode, `-e` is *still* recognized as enabling backslash procession, rather than as an ordinary word:

```
$ bash --posix -c 'echo -e foo\\nbar'
foo
bar
```

When `xpg_echo` is enabled, making `-e` unnecessary, *now* it is properly treated as an ordinary argument in POSIX mode:

```
$ bash --posix -O xpg_echo -c 'echo -e foo\\nbar'
-e foo
bar
```

To avoid these portability issues, use `printf` instead, which historically did not have as many diverging implementations, and is much more portable in practice than `echo`.

Comment: Re “newer versions of `bash` require the `xpg_echo` option to be set for `echo` to behave according to the POSIX standard”: How is `echo` not behaving according to the POSIX standard? The [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html) says “if any of the operands contain a backslash ( '\' ) character, the results are implementation-defined.” So either interpreting backslash sequences or not interpreting backslash sequences conforms to that, as long as it is documented.

Comment: Backslash escapes are specified for the X/Open System Interfaces (XSI) extension to POSIX; POSIX itself says the behavior of `echo` in the face of their presence is implementation-defined. The standard also says that `echo` shall not take any options, so adding an option like `-e` to get "POSIX behavior" is somewhat paradoxical.  As I understand it, `-e` stands for "escape" and just means "honor backslash escapes in the string", nothing to do with POSIX compliance.

Comment: Yes, POSIX allows backslashed characters to be implementation defined, but only the `-n` "option" is implementation defined. `-e` *must* be output as an argument per POSIX. I guess it would be more accurate to say that `-e` enables the XSI extension to process backslashes in the arguments. I will update the answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `printf` instead of `echo`.

Support for `-e` with `echo` is very shell- and platform-specific, while `printf` usually just works.

(Bash's builtin command `echo` support `-e`, but some other shell's don't)

Example:

```
printf "%b" "foo\nbar"
```

Comment: Using `printf` alone, as in `printf SomeString`, will interpret `%` sequences in the string as format specifications. The `%b` specification should be used, as in `printf "%b" SomeString`.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't know for sure that the string doesn't contain any format specifiers (e.g. a user input), then `printf` should definitely be used like that.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should use `printf` instead of `echo`, since it's consistent across shells.

But you must be doing something a bit unusual; out of the box,  `echo -e` works fine in bash on macOS, even in the relatively ancient version 3.2 shipped as /bin/bash:

```
bash-3.2$ uname -s
Darwin
bash-3.2$ echo -e foo
foo
bash-3.2$ echo -e 'foo\nbar'
foo
bar
```

Are you perhaps explicitly running the separate program `/bin/echo`? If so, don't do that; just type the command name `echo` without the path. That way you get the `echo` that's built into the shell; if you ask for the separate program by explicit pathname, that's what gets run instead.

Or maybe you're turning on POSIX mode? You said you were starting the shell with `bash` and not `sh`, which is the usual way to get POSIX behavior, but you can still explicitly turn on POSIX mode with `set -o posix`. If you've done that, you'll see the same sort of `echo` behavior as the /bin version. You can turn that off with `set +o posix`.

If you want consistency regardless of mode, I recommend switching to `printf`. It works a little differently, most notably in that it takes a format string followed by the values to fill in, and doesn't automatically append a newline the way `echo` does; `echo "$var"` becomes `printf '%s\n' "$var"`. But it is consistent.

Comment: In bash, `echo -e foo` executes bash’s builtin `echo` command, not the one in `/bin`. So it is not correct that “`echo -e` works fine in bash on macOS, even in the relatively ancient version shipped in /bin”.

Comment: The relatively ancient version _OF BASH_ shipped in /bin:  /bin/bash on macOS is 3.2.  I wasn't talking about /bin/echo there; I addressed it in my second paragraph.

Comment: The point is the statement ”`echo -e` works fine in bash on macOS, even in the relatively ancient version shipped in /bin” is false. OP reports they observed an `echo -e` command printing `-e`, so it is clear that some version of echo that did not support `-e` was executed for them, and telling them it works fine is wrong and does not answer their question.

Comment: Their characterization of the problem was inaccurate. My answer is not "works fine here"; I gave an example of echo's behavior from bash on macOS to show that something else must be going on. I then provided a possible candidate for that "something else" (explicitly running /bin/echo instead of the builtin).

Comment: The problem isn't that `echo -e` does't work, but that it *shouldn't* work in POSIX mode, which requires `-e` to be treated like an ordinary word to output, rather than enabling behavior that `echo` should already exhibit.

Comment: Is it possible, that it is caused by `""`: `echo -e "$STATUS"`